# Is the App Engine Task Queue example code out of date?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm having some issues with the docs for Task Queues.

The sample code here: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/overview-push doesn't seem correct, when compared to the rest of the docs.

I get errors trying to pass params to the add method of the Queue.

If it is out of date, does anyone know of a similarly simple example for how to use Queues?

My code:

```
test_queue.add('/workers/testworker', params={'id': testmodel.key().id()})
TypeError: add() got an unexpected keyword argument 'params'
```

Sample Code in Docs:

```
taskqueue.add(url='/worker', params={'key': key})
```

The Queue documentation seems utterly different than the sample code would suggest, accepting only two params:

"add(task, transactional=False)"

Just trying to figure out if I should pretty much ignore this sample code, or if I'm doing something very dumb.

Comment: Can you post what error you are getting and your code?

Comment: Edited with some more stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are two different ways of doing the same thing. The example from the overview page accesses the overall `taskqueue` function, as you can see from the import.

Your code is (presumably, though you don't show it) create a TaskQueue instance, which you've called `test_queue`, and then calling `add` on it. As you've discovered, the `add` method of a Task instance only accepts a Task instance and the transactional parameter.

Comment: Quirky. Seems like both adds could accept the same parameters easily.

Answer (score 0):

The official GAE example needs a serious update and more elaboration. Are there any good and complete examples of push taskqueue out there?